# Accessing Ejabberd local instance with smack android

Tags: android, ejabberd, smack

I set up a local instance of the ejabberd,by using pidgin I tested it and was working fine, I needed to make an android clientside for it ,

created an android project as per the article : [smack-api-android](https://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/)
The UI of the app is like [this](https://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/),

The thing I need to know is when we are using ejabberd in local how will I find out which is the service name?

I am just a beginner in android, any advices will be useful

Answer (score 1):

With Smack, the service name may be the XMPP domain or IP adress.